# How do I modify the container size and colors in Twitter bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a mockup here

http://jsfiddle.net/uwL8r/

I have tried to change to container size to 640px but this seems to have no effect.  I would also like to change the background color of the 'hero' CSS and I'm wondering if it is possible to do so in the HTML without directly modifying the CSS file (which I would like to leave as unchanged as possible to)

Comment: You want to change the styles without modifying the bootstrap css or any css? You can always add inline styles although it's bad practice.

Comment: For the container size happy to modify anyway possible including direct CSS

Comment: Look into this, This will be helpful in this regard.[ See the code](
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/stepping-out-with-bootstrap-from-twitter/)

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding your request correctly, but it seems trivial to just set some css rules: http://jsfiddle.net/uwL8r/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own style sheet, style.css, and change the hero-unit color there. It will overwrite the bootstrap settings without having to touch the original code.

When you are changing the  container width, make sure you change it in the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file because that is referenced last in your header which will overwrite any changes done in `bootstrap.css`.

Comment: Not sure this is an appropriate answer as the OP mentioned that they did not want to modify the CSS files.